# From which directory to run python Script in webserver

Tags: php, python

I am trying to run a python script from a webserver(apache) using php. I used the following command

exec (python test.py $arg1 $arg2 , $output, $result)

It executes successfully when I put the test.py in the document root directory. However, I wanted to run the python script from another subdirectory so that it would be easy for me to manage the outout of the python script.

what the python script does is

1. creates a folder
2. copy a file from the same directory the python script resides into the folder created (1)
3. zip the folder

The document root and the subdirectory for the python script have the same permission.

since it keeps on looking for the files to be copied from the documentroot, it generates "no such file or directory" error (in the apache error log file)

Comment: What do you mean by "run the script in another subdirectory"?  Change the location of `test.py`?  Change what the script thinks is the current working directory?  Something else?

Comment: I want to run the python script from a directory different from the document root

Comment: you can try to put the php file and python script in the directory you want to run the python script. if you can't move the php file, then you can call chdir() first before call exec().

Comment: @AynalemTesfaye
May be it is a good idea for you to show us the test.py too. May be for debugging you could try using absolute path instead of assuming current dir. Again sharing your test.py code will help answer your question a lot.

Comment: @gipsy I have tried using absolute path as well. But I dont understand why it looks for the file to be copied from the document root where the php resides

Comment: @AynalemTesfaye That is because , php is the one invoking it. You can find the current directory by : ```os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))```

Comment: @gipsy you are right. I now solved my problem by just putting the python and the other files in the document root. Then execute the command mv to move the folder created by the python script. Because I cannot move the php file (i am using wordpress)to the folder where the python resides

Answer (score 0):

if your python file and php file in same folder:

`$command_to_run = "test.pyw $arg1 $arg2 , $output, $result";
 $response = shell_exec($command_to_run);`

else:

`$command_to_run = "<php_folder>/scripts/python/test.pyw $arg1 $arg2 , $output, $result";
 $response = shell_exec($command_to_run);`